# PySide: QThread event handling

Tags: python, pyside, qthread

I have been researching the following issue on PySide threading, but I have found very little documentation so here goes a long post on my findings hoping for some concise feedback about how it goes.
Supposing we are building a multi-threaded GUI application that invokes some linux processes.
We will be using QThread class to call a QProcess from within with the objective of having the application running multiple processess simultaneously when it is ready (in different threads)

I am using just a QThread Class and starting through the QApplication main loop

**Case 1**:
- We connect the thread termination signal to another function of the same class that calls self.exit (so that the thread class exits)
- No call to self.exec_() as instructed in the official documentation of PySide http://tinyurl.com/qh7cooa

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.2
from PySide import QtGui
from PySide import QtCore
import sys, random

class ProcThread(QtCore.QThread):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ProcThread, self).__init__(parent)

    def run(self):
        try:
            self.qproc = QtCore.QProcess()
            self.finished.connect(self.threadFinished)
            filename = "/home/user1/Desktop/fileno"+str(random.randint(1, 10000))+".txt"
            self.qproc.start("touch", [filename])       
        except Exception as error:
            print(str(error))
            raise(error)

    #self.exec_()

    def threadFinished(self):
        print("Thread has finished")
        self.qproc.close()

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv) 
procthread = ProcThread()
procthread.start()
app.exec_()
```

*RESULT*: The thread termination is caught (message "Thread has finished" gets printed), the process does run (file is created) but the application DOES NOT EXIT

**Case 2**: Same as before, but now also calling `self._exec()` (uncommenting the relevant line in previous code snippet)
*RESULT*: The thread termination is NOT caught, the process does run (file is created) and once again the application DOES NOT EXIT (remains as a background job) after Ctrl+Z / have to kill it explicitly

**Case 3**: Now connecting the signal emmitted when the `QProcess` terminates through `self.qproc.finished.connect(self.threadFinished)`.
No call to self.exec_()

only citing code between try-except - #self.exec_() remains commented

```
self.qproc = QtCore.QProcess()
self.qproc.finished.connect(self.threadFinished)
filename = "/home/pantelis/Desktop/fileno" + str(random.randint(1, 10000)) + ".txt"
self.qproc.start("touch", [filename])
```

*RESULT*: As in Case 2 - The thread termination is NOT caught, the process does run (file is created) and once again the application DOES NOT EXIT

**Case 4**: As in Case 1, but now adding the following line in `threadFinished`
`self.exit()`
*RESULT*: As in Case 2 - The thread termination is NOT caught, the process does run (file is created) and once again the application DOES NOT EXIT

**Case 5**: As in Case 4, just uncommenting the `self.exec_()`
RESULTS: Thread termination IS CAUGHT (message "Thread has finished" gets printed), file IS created and once again the application DOES NOT EXIT

**Cases 6, 7, 8**: Added `self.qproc.close() / self.qproc.terminate() / self.qproc.kill()` in `threadFinished` to explicitly terminate the QProcess from the specific function
*RESULT*: As in Case 5

One could also try different alternatives, such as linking the `self.terminated` signal of `QThread` to `threadFinished` and so on.
Some very rough questions although I guess is a complex issue:
- Why although formal documentation states that call to `QThread`'s `exec_()` function is necessary for the thread to start event handling, this seems to be occurring without a call to the specific functions
- In some cases thread termination is caught / processed by `threadFinished` and in some it is not
- most importantly: why doesn't the application terminate? (I have also tried `app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)`)

Answer (score 2):

Just call `app.quit()` in your `threadFinished` handler, and if you have visible widgets, `hide()` and `destroy()` the main window, this should take care of destroying all children.